# how to declare type conversion in header file and implement in cpp file?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operator-overloading

it doesn't work for me.
i have a header file and a cpp file.
need to define a conversion operator from my class to INT, but it gives me "syntax error" when declaring it in the H file and implementing in the cpp file. maybe i got the syntax wrong?
in the H file i have in "public":

```
operator int();
```

and in the cpp file i have:

```
A::operator int() { return mNumber ;}
```

if i implement the function in the H file it works, but i don't want to do that. 
can anyone help?

Comment: I would make the method `const`. Don't think it affects the problem but semantically I doubt your conversion is supposed to modify `A`.

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: What you posted worked for me with the assumption that `mNumber` is an int member variable. As @avakar says, please post the error.

Comment: Compiles fine in gcc 4.0.3. What error message are you getting?

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to include the h file in the cpp file? Sometimes shit like this happens... but it would really help to know what error you're getting

Comment: it appears to be working now. 
i use Eclipse and for some reason it started working only when i used the "clean project" option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also wanted to separate the class declaration from the implementation.  The critical missing ingredient was the `const`:

```
// Foobar.hpp
class Foobar
{
    public:
        Foobar() : _v(42) {}

        operator int() const;

    private:

        int _v;
};
```

And then in the implementation file:

```
#include "Foobar.hpp"

Foobar::operator int() const
{
    return _v;
}
```

See this [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)